# R - is it possible to use the $ operator with variables of character strings?

Tags: r, string, operators

Suppose I have a vector of character strings that I'd like to use to name new columns in a data.frame. I could do this:

```
my_strings = c("Some", "Strings", "Here")
for (i in my_strings) {
  df[,i] = 1
}
```

And get three new columns in the `df` name appropriately. But if instead I did

```
my_strings = c("Some", "Strings", "Here")
for (i in my_strings) {
  df$i = 1
}
```

I'll just get one new column named "i". This isn't a problem with data frames but some objects are difficult or impossible to modify without using the `$` operator - is there some way to feed it a variable to interpret as a character?

Comment: Can you give an example of this non-data frame in which the dollar sign access of columns is an issue? This sounds like a data type-specific issue and it is difficult to give an accurate answer without knowing what that data type is. Otherwise, I don't think it's possible to use the dollar sign like you want.

Comment: No, it's not. You can always use `[[`, i.e., `your_object[[i]] = 1`. See `fortunes::fortune(312)`, `fortunes::fortune(343)`, and the dupe. (Happy to re-open if you can provide an example where `$` works but `[[` doesn't.)